# Setup for including commentators in live stream (including monitoring)

Tags: audio, live, latency

I'm currently planning a live stream setup which has to include two commentators. This is a bit of a make shift / low budget production. Our setup will be

- Panasonic Mixer with 4 SD Inputs to pre-mix four cameras. The PGM will go into
- Blackmagic TV Studio, for additional 2 Cameras + Titles

The resulting PGM will go into the encoder to be streamed.

Now those commentators need to hear the program audio, but not themselves. My first idea was to plug a de-embedder into the PGM output of the TV Studio, feed this audio to the commentators AND into an audio mixer to include the two microphones. The resulting audio will got to the encoder. But I'm pretty sure this will cause a delay through the mixers latency and audio will be out of sync, right?

What is the best way to include the commentators AND get the "clean" audio for them? Remember the BM TV Studio has NO audio output. Only an audio input where I could feed the mics. But then I have no "clean" sound ...

Can anyone offer advice?

Thanks!
thomas

Answer (score 2):

When I first started doing this, I always thought it was better to give them "clean" audio as well. I've since figured out that they want to hear themselves. Also they want to hear each other, so really you do not want a separate feed for them.

Depending on what you are broadcasting, you may not even need the sound from the event.

The only issue you're going to run in with a delay in the video to them commentating is if they are only using the video feed to do it, not the live event going on right there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to make some changes in your system:

- add some sound mixer to mix all the mics and create 'intersound'
  signal
- add a commentators unit for 2-3 commentators and/or guest - it will
  solve most of you problems, there are many models from Glensound,
  Sonofex, CTP and others
- combine intersound with commentators' mix to create 'program sound'
  using the same audio mixer
- connect it to BM TV Studio audio input, analog-to AES converter may
  be required because   BM's device has no analog audio inputs, only
  unbalanced AES one.

Combined sound to be embedded into program output using built-in audio embedder. In the simplest case you just can mix sound from commentators unit with camera mics in BM TV Studio.